# How to select a column field by joining two tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

i want to select amount by joining two tables.
This is my active record. Through this i want to select 'amount' from 'programme' table with these conditions. Please help

`Programme.joins(:subscriptions).where('programmes.coach_id=?',params[:id])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use select method and specify column like:-

```
Programme.joins(:subscriptions).where('programmes.coach_id = ?', params[:id]).select("programmes.amount")
```

Join multiple table as:-

```
Programme.joins(:subscriptions, :students).where('programmes.coach_id = ?', params[:id]).select("programmes.amount")
```

Comment: in the same table how can i join students table